# Динамическое подключение js скрипта

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, ajax-load

Пишу сайт интернет-магазин. В качестве инструментов голые php,js,css,mysql. Вопрос в следующем, на странице с товарами при загрузке делаю ajax запрос на php(вытаскиваю из базы товары) и при возврате json из базы в цикле динамически создаю товары. В каждом div товара динамически в некоторых тегах прописываю разные id(назначаю от id товаров) и цепляю к каждому товару onclick() со своими аргументами. Для этого всего, мне приходится, при каждом таком ajax запросе динамически переподключать файлик main.js ,где лежат скрипты на обработку анимаций нажатий на товар и т.д. Где то читал, что это происходит потому что файл js , подключаемый до того,как товары с разными id динамически появились не может распознать их, ибо скриптово-событийный подход. Как сделать что то на подобии php-autoload ,чтобы js скрипты внешние не загружать по сто раз?

Comment: вы что-то делаете не так, скрипты многократно скачивать уж точно не нужно

Comment: это в основном касаемо функции добавления в корзину, когда на определенном товаре кликаешь на Добавить в корзину, именно под ним должно быть +1, а по др.нет.

Comment: почитайте про делегирование событий